# How to convert user entered date string into JavaScript date format

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate age of the user when user entered their date of birth. I got user entered value via text field. But I got output as NaN. I think there is an error in converting string to date. This is my code.

```js
function printage() {
  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;


  var age;
  var past;
  var now;
  var a;

  past = dob.getDate();
  a = Date.parse(past);
  now = Date.now();
  age = now - past;

  var millisecond = age;
  var second = 1000;
  var minute = second * 60;
  var hour = minute * 60;
  var day = hour * 24;
  var year = day * 365;

  var years = Math.round(millisecond / (day * 365));
  var message = "Age in years" + years;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = years;





}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <label for="age">Enter your date of birth</label>
  <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob">
  <button onclick="printage()" type="button">Age</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In what format user is supposed to enter the date? `11 May 2000`, `May 11 2000`, `11-05-2000`?

Comment: Why don't you use `input type ="date"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use `past=new Date(dob)` instead of `getDate()`

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="age">Enter your date of birth</label>
  <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob">
  <button onclick="printage()" type="button">Age</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    function printage() {
      var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
      var age;
      var past;
      var now;
      var a;
      past =new Date(dob);
      console.log(past)
      a = Date.parse(past);
      now = Date.now();
      age = now - past;
      var millisecond = age;
      var second = 1000;
      var minute = second * 60;
      var hour = minute * 60;
      var day = hour * 24;
      var year = day * 365;
      var years = Math.round(millisecond / (day * 365));
      var message = "Age in years" + years;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = years;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per some comments you can also use input type date directly. No need for any conversion